# Regarding heat maps

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/selecting-multiple-areas-map/

Please see the above link map i want to make something like this could anyone please share the details of how i could make it moreover i have to make for my particular state how i could do all this.

I have tried few things with google fusion tables but didnt able to get this layout and the js file used in this is different how i can make my own

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are certain steps that you need to follow to make this feature work:

- First you have to define the borders of all the US states. This can be obtained by passing the lat/lng values of the borders. Please refer to this [JS file](http://mapscripting.com/examples/overlays/statesobj.js) which has the Lat/Lng of US states along the border. Draw Polygon using code.

  var statesobj = {"AK": [new google.maps.LatLng(70.0187, -141.0205),
  new google.maps.LatLng(70.1292, -141.7291),
  new google.maps.LatLng(70.4515, -144.8163)]}

So, it's easy now. Loop on these lat/longs. And you can draw the polygons on every state of US.

- Secondly, Consider all the regions/states drawn on the Google Maps as polygon. Then you have to pass to the polygon object a new PolygonOptions by calling this method:

  ```
  setOptions(options:PolygonOptions).
  ```

You can see the different options here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PolygonOptions

In this PolygonOptions you can then specify the color you want the Polygon to be filled with along with all the other stuff you could want to change.

You can also set the click to zoom in. That can be done using

```
map.setCenter(Polygon.getPosition());    //Polygon is Polygon to center on
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
```